# How to loop through Columns of a Pyspark DataFrame and apply operations column-wise

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a Pyspark Dataframe, and when I run this code

`queries_df.select(*(queries_df[i] for i in range(5))).show(5)`

I get the following answer (which is what I expected):

```
+----------+----------------+--------+-------+-------------+
|query_time|210 mini netbook|47lv5500|antenna|apple macbook|
+----------+----------------+--------+-------+-------------+
|2011-08-11|               1|       1|     10|            5|
|2011-08-12|               1|       0|      0|           10|
|2011-08-15|               0|       0|      3|            0|
|2011-08-17|               0|       0|      0|            0|
|2011-08-18|               5|       0|      0|            0|
+----------+----------------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

I need to loop through each column, and in each individual column, apply a subtraction element by element. Something like the `numpy.diff()` function.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to get each individual row.

When I do:

```
diff_arrays = queries_df.select(*(queries_df[i] for i in range(1,5)))
.rdd.map(lambda a: a)

diff_arrays.collect()
```

I get a list of Rows objects:

```
[Row(210 mini netbook=1, 47lv5500=1, antenna=10, apple macbook=5),
 Row(210 mini netbook=1, 47lv5500=0, antenna=0, apple macbook=10),
 Row(210 mini netbook=0, 47lv5500=0, antenna=0, apple macbook=0),
 Row(210 mini netbook=0, 47lv5500=0, antenna=0, apple macbook=0), ... ]
```

But when I try to apply a `reduce` operation, I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reduce'`

This is what I am trying:

```
diff_arrays.foreach(lambda column: column).reduce(some_function)
```

Does anyone have an idea about how I can achieve this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

To make it more clear, I'll change the example table and provide an expected output.

When I run the appropriate code to apply the differences, I would like to get an answer as follows:

```
+------------------+-----+-----+----+---+
| 210 mini netbook |   0 |  -1 |  0 | 5 |
| 47lv5500         |  -1 |   0 |  0 | 0 |
| antenna          | -10 |   3 | -3 | 0 |
| apple macbook    |   5 | -10 |  0 | 0 |
+------------------+-----+-----+----+---+
```